# Universal Parse Primitive Type on C#

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I have string value and `Type` of some variable (For example `int` and `"32"` or `bool` and `true`). My type is primitive type. Can I parse string to my type in one line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Yes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx)

```
Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
object res = Convert.ChangeType("123", myType);
```